# Collections inside Meteor.call doesn't update server data

Tags: meteor

In my `sever/publish.js`, I have something like this:

```js
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");

Meteor.publish("questions", function(){
    return Questions.find();
});
```

In my `client/app.js` whenever I do something like this:

```js
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");

var questionHandle = Meteor.subscribe("questions");

Meteor.methods({
    post: function(title){
        Questions.insert({title: title});
    }
});

$('.save').on('click', function(){
    var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    Meteor.call('post', title);
});
```

It doesn't work! But if I put the code outside itself, the server data updates.

```js
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");

var questionHandle = Meteor.subscribe("questions");

$('.save').on('click', function(){
    var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    Questions.insert({title: title});
});
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method has to be defined on the **server** if you want to update the real server database. If you define it on the client as well it will be run first ("latency compensation)".

```js
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");

Meteor.methods({
    post: function(title){
        Questions.insert({title: title});
    }
});

if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("questions", function(){
      return Questions.find();
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient){
  var questionHandle = Meteor.subscribe("questions");

  $('.save').on('click', function(){
      var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
      Meteor.call('post', title);
  });
}
```

You can see the [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods), and [EventedMind screencast](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-methods).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Worked like a charm!